# Easiest way to create mbtiles files of Openstreetmap extracts?

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

I'm creating an iPhone travel app that uses online as well as offline maps.  For the offline maps I want to allow users to download an mbtiles file of the area they are interested in (e.g. London).  The map should have information such as roads etc.. that are already found in OpenStreetmap. I'm aware of web sites such as http://metro.teczno.com/ for downloading Openstreetmap extracts.  What is the easiest way to create mbtiles files of Openstreetmap extracts?  Note: no map customization is needed.   I've tried using TileMill, but I'm not able to see the correct map information.  Most information on this says to load quite a few other tools and the instructions are not easy to follow or they don't work and since I don't need map customization, it should not really be needed.  My main/preferred work environments are Windows, Mac and Ubuntu (using VirtualBox under Windows) in that order.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 4):

These things are never really easy, but I've tried to make them as easy as possible in [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net). In a few days I'll be releasing a new version which supports creating MBTiles from OSM XML files. In the meantime, you can read the older tutorial which generates tiles as individual files for the web map server. Since you don't need map customization, you can skip some of the steps: http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/9921938947/maperitive-tutorial-a-hiking-web-map-in-ten-easy-steps

Comment: Hi Igor, This looks very impressive and very promising. I can't wait to try out the new version with export to MBTiles. I assume that it will export the area displayed and allow the selection of min max zoom levels. If it also estimates the ouput file size that would be great.  Thanks Tom

Comment: Looks great. Sadly Mono isn't able to run your app on Mac OSX 10.8.2 - crashes on startup. I think you're on the case though judging by your google groups responses (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/maperitive/YAXxJNBzZH8)

Comment: Did you release that version you wrote about? I've downloaded the Maperitive but can't see any option to export to mbtiles.

Comment: @AtanuCSE sure, it's just not available through the menu, but the command is described here: http://maperitive.net/docs/Commands/GenerateMBTiles.html

Comment: @IgorBrejc how get complete world mbTiles? just like google earth

Answer (score 4):

Few days ago I have written an article on [my website](http://mapit-gis.com/offline-maps) - it's a step by step process on how to generate PNG raster mbtiles from OSM data.

I am heavy mbtiles user and few weeks ago I did manage to deploy a solution based on **node.js** and **Mapnik**. Its very fast, convenient and one line command solution.

The steps to follow are:

1. Download and install node.js – make sure it’s **32Bit version** otherwise **Mapnik** will not work.
2. Install Python if you do not have it already.
3. Install Mapnik executing command in the node.js console:

   ```
   npm install -g tl @mapbox/mbtiles tilelive-http
   ```
4. When the installation is successful you should be able to execute command:
   -z (min zoom level), -Z (max zoom level)

   ```
   tl copy -z 0 -Z 15 -b "19.481506 49.050920 20.407791 49.319751"  "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" mbtiles://./tatra.mbtiles
   ```

This will create test mbtiles file for Tatra mountains and if you are on Windows the file will be located in C:\Users{your_user_name}\ folder

Due to low reputation I am not able to include URLs or pictures, but I have documented the process [over here](http://mbtilesmap.com/generate-mbtiles-node-js-mapnik).

Comment: Could you explain the answer here; it is convention to not rely on links to external sites when answering questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Hi beresforrdt, I will update the answer over weekend. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can create MBTiles from any .osm.pbf file using this tool - https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker

1. Download .osm.pbf file from [Geofabric](https://download.geofabrik.de/) or any other source
2. Download [tilemaker](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/releases)
3. Execute the following command

```
tilemaker --input netherlands.osm.pbf --output netherlands.mbtiles --process resources/process-openmaptiles.lua --config resources/config-openmaptiles.json
```

You can read more about it in this blog post - https://blog.kleunen.nl/blog/tilemaker-generate-map