# Osmdroid only view grid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using Osmdroid for loading offline map. I am refer from [article](http://www.sieswerda.net/2012/08/15/upping-the-developer-friendliness/)

When I run my project, it's just display a grid. I don't know why, I Try some approach but don't anything change.
[image]

My mainActivity snip code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    resProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    String packageDir = "/Osmdroid";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + packageDir;
    File dbFile = new File(path, "map.mbtiles");
    if (dbFile.exists()) {
        provider = new MBTileProvider(this, dbFile);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView = new MapView(getApplicationContext(), 
        provider.getTileSource().getTileSizePixels(), resProxy, provider);
    }
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(provider.getMinimumZoomLevel());
    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(10.813472, 106.666105);
    mapController.animateTo(gPt);
}
```

Please, How to resolve this ?

***Resolved***

I researched on internet and I found a solution to resolve my problem. Following from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721543/easiest-way-to-create-mbtiles-files-of-openstreetmap-extracts) of @osedok. I don't know why it's just working with mbtiles file by sources, otherwise it's fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiation `mapView` from your layout file then changing it.. try setting the created instance as your content view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    resProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    String packageDir = "/Osmdroid";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + packageDir;
    File dbFile = new File(path, "map.mbtiles");
    if (dbFile.exists()) {
        provider = new MBTileProvider(this, dbFile);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView = new MapView(getApplicationContext(), 
                              provider.getTileSource().getTileSizePixels(),
                              resProxy, 
                              provider);
    }
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(provider.getMinimumZoomLevel());
    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(10.813472, 106.666105);
    mapController.animateTo(gPt);

    // here is the important part
    // Set the MapView as the root View for this Activity; done!
    setContentView(mapView);
}
```

*P.S:* Make sure your `dbFile` exists

Comment: Hey. The first times, I have tried your way, but it's still not working. I'm sure my dbFile exists. Do I need setting something else?

Comment: have you tried without `mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);`? also check your tileprovider

Comment: You can follow this link on [How to use osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)

Comment: I am just using mbtiles file type. In Osmdoid docs write that : Caveats and exemptions
MBTiles does not store a tile source name in the database. Calling IArchiveFile.getTileSources will return an empty set in this case. On the flip side, MBTiles files will display to on the map regardless of what tile source the mapView is set to.

Comment: It is possible to remove all checks for tile source name comparisons for offline tiles, which would in effect, create a composite tile source. This could work out great if your archives don't overlap. To do this, extend the existing IArchiveFile providers to remove the checks, then register them as the with the ArchiveFileFactory